# Finding difference between two lists and creating a zero-one list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that takes two list compares them and give back a list which shows where the first list is different from the other one.Some examples follows:

- Example 1:

  ```
  list1: [1, 2, 3]
  list2: [1, 3]
  desired result: [0, 1, 0]
  ```
- Example 2

  ```
  list1: [1, 3, 1, 2, 4]
  list2: [1, 1, 4]
  desired result: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
  ```
- Example 3

  ```
  list1: [3, 5, 2, 9, 9]
  list2: [3, 5, 9, 9]
  desired result: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  ```
- Example 4

  ```
  list1: [1, 1, 1]
  list2: [1]
  desired result: [0, 1, 1]
  ```
- Example 5

  ```
  list1: [1, 2, 2, 1]
  list2: [1, 2, 1]
  desired result: [0, 0, 1, 0]
  ```

Some facts:

- `list1` is always bigger or equal length with the `list2`
- `desired list` has the length of the `list1`
- The number of ones in the desired list is equal with the difference of the length of the two lists.

My apologies that I do not provide any answer but I can not think of any way to implement this. Any guidance/tip?

Comment: What should the output be when `list1` is `[1,2]` and `list2` is `[3]`?

Comment: thanks for the question. I was trying to edit my question on it. will do soon. Thats not possible. In a point of view list2 comes 'somehow' form list1.

Comment: I don't understand why the last two are `.. 1, 0]` in your second example....

Comment: Lot of ambiguity in your Samples. Need deeper explanation. For `ex`: in your 2nd Sample, why is diff of `1` and `4` a `0` ?

Comment: What should the output be when `list1` is `[1,1]` and `list2` is `[1]`?

Comment: I have updated my question with more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try:

```
def compute_difference(list1, list2):
    result = []
    iter1 = iter(list1)
    for item2 in list2:
        for item1 in iter1:
            if item2 == item1:
                result.append(0)
                break
            else:
                result.append(1)
    for item1 in iter1:
        result.append(1)

    return result

assert compute_difference([1,2,3],[1,3]) == [0, 1, 0]
assert compute_difference([1, 3, 1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 4]) == [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
assert compute_difference([3, 5, 2, 9, 9], [3, 5, 9, 9]) == [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you:

```
desired = []
list1= [1, 3, 1, 2, 4]
list2= [1, 1, 4]
j = 0;
for i in range(len(list2)):
    while(list1[j] != list2[i]):
        desired.append(1)
        j+=1
    desired.append(0)
    j += 1

print (desired)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as others but this will work. Basically you just check for membership between the lists. If it's there then append a 0, otherwise append a 1 to a new list.

```
list1 = [3, 5, 2, 9, 9]
list2 = [3, 5, 9, 9]
# desired result: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

result = []
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    # print(list1[i])
    if list1[i] in list2:
        result.append(0)
    else:
        result.append(1)
print(result)
```

I hope this helps.